# Push notifications, where are they?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, push-notification

I had to include some js from a large company that's doing business with my employer. Apparently that js includes push notifications.

The page I'm making now asks "would you like to receive notifications?". How can I, in Chrome, find the line of code that's causing the prompt?

I've opened up devtools and searched for "notification" "subscribe" "pushmanager" etc in the "search all files" function & don't see it in there. I just want to know what they're making us include.

Answer (score 0):

You should look for push notification subscription code. It should look like this:

```
serviceWorkerRegistration.pushManager.subscribe()
```

Search for one of these terms and you should find the piece of code you are looking for.

Comment: I don't see it anywhere, they must have obscured it somehow.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the other answer is correct (I honestly don't know)..

```
var swr = serviceWorkerRegistration.pushManager.subscribe;
serviceWorkerRegistration.pushManager.subscribe = function(){
    swr();
    console.log((new Error()).stack);
};
```

This should print the stack trace in the console whenever that function is called, allowing you to find the origin script and line numbers and stuff..